# limit a float list into 10 digits

Tags: python, dictionary, floating-point

I have a list import from a data file.

```
lines=['1628.246', '100.0000', '0.4563232E-01', '0.4898217E-01', '0.3017656E-02', '0.2271272', '0.2437533', '0.1500232E-01', '0.4102987', '0.4117742', '0.5461504E-02', '2.080838', '0.5527303E-03', '-0.4542367E-03', '-0.2238781E-01', '-0.8196812E-03', '-0.3796306E-01', '-0.7906407E-03', '-0.6738000E-03', '0.000000']
```

I want to generate a new list include all element in same 10 digits and put back to file
Here is I did:

```
newline=map(float,lines)
newline=map("{:.10f}".format,newline)
newline=map(str,newline)
jitterfile.write(join(newline)+'\n')
```

It works, but looks not beautiful.  Any idea to make it good looking?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a single line like so:

```
    newline=["{:.10f}".format(float(i)) for i in lines]
    jitterfile.write(join(newline)+'\n')
```

Of note, your third instruction `newline=map(str,newline)` is redundant as the entries in the list are already strings, so casting them is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

The map function also accept lambda , also as the result of `format` is string you don't need to apply the `str` on your list ,and you need to use join with a delimiter like ',':

```
>>> newline=map(lambda x:"{:.10f}".format(float(x)),newline)
>>> newline
['1628.2460000000', '100.0000000000', '0.0456323200', '0.0489821700', '0.0030176560', '0.2271272000', '0.2437533000', '0.0150023200', '0.4102987000', '0.4117742000', '0.0054615040', '2.0808380000', '0.0005527303', '-0.0004542367', '-0.0223878100', '-0.0008196812', '-0.0379630600', '-0.0007906407', '-0.0006738000', '0.0000000000']
jitterfile.write(','.join(newline)+'\n')
```